# how do i make the form inputs rtl without a lot of duplicates

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4

How would make the form **RTL**, if the locale
isn't English, is there a way to change the locale in CSS instead of duplicates a lot of codes to every input to make it **RTL**, If the condition is true?

for exmaple:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-name">
    <label for="name" class=" control-label {{ app()->getLocale() == 'ar' ? 'float-right' : ''}}">{{ __('user.User') }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
               value="{{ isset($user->name) ? $user->name :'' }}" maxlength="50" required=""
               class="form-control {{ app()->getLocale() == 'ar' ? 'text-right' : ''}}">
        <span style="color: red" class="help-block {{ app()->getLocale() == 'ar' ? 'float-right' : ''}}"></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

I don't want to duplicate all the conditions in every input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using bootstrap4 just change the direction of your document to be RTL

so you have to do this

```
body {direction:rtl}
```

in your external rtl css file for " RTL direction " and put it after your main css style to override on it .

the other way is to write rtl styling css data at the end of your main css file but detect every class by any html property related to rtl version

like :

```
html[lang="ar"] body {
  direction:rtl
}
/* the same for any other elements */
html[lang="ar"] .class-name {
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:20px
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you made my day =)

Answer (score 0):

if this is just a form and nothing complicated what you have written already would work.
make a class for rtl and align right
if langauge is arabic of persian or any other language that needs rtl design add to the classes otherwise don't add it.

Oh I thought of something right now, that might work in your case. in laravel the langauge code would be added to the lang tag in the head of the website. you can get the tag with javascript and if language is arabic add a class otherwise don't.

both CSS and JS are possible but for long run if you have a complicated design, a new page would also be a good idea.
your choice.

Comment: bro, I know that's work correct but I have a lot of forms. I don't need to make this every new form.

Comment: then i guess you can go with the js option. it would be faster and you wouldn't have to do it for all the forms.

Comment: see if this document.documentElement.lang would give you the language of your website so you could change it in js

Comment: is possible to make something like  if app()->getLocal == 'ar'  .input { addClass ='float-right' }

Comment: i don't think so. write the applocale to <html lang="ar"> for example then with the js line I wrote above you can get the language. then get all the inputs of the page with js again and add class to them

Comment: but in this way, I should duplicate functions for every new form with different inputs

Comment: no no no, by getting the input I meant give them a class or get them by tag so you could select all of them together. when you get by class name or if you use jquery and write something like $(".inputClass") then you can select all the inputs. you would have another class called "rtlInputClass" for example and then after if language is ar then get input class and add rtlinputclass it would add this class to all the inputs on your page. you don't need to write the function for each input. just make sure you would call the function when the documents loads so it would start the magic :)

Comment: thanks, this way looks so good, but @Ahmed El-sayed solved my problem.

Comment: yes, his way is actually much much simpler :)))) but be careful direction applies to all the elements and in some old browsers it might not be supported. have a good day mate

Answer (score 0):

1) Append lang="ar" attribute to your html element or any single element you want to make RTL
2) in CSS:

```
[lang="ar"] {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: can you explain more, please? it looks like what I need

Comment: You can read about direction property here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction